# Swift 4 consistently calls wrong #selector

Tags: ios, selector, swift4

I have a small library, [McPicker](https://github.com/kmcgill88/McPicker-iOS), that uses some subclassed `UIBarButtonItem`'s which have `#selector`'s to dismiss or cancel a `UIPickerView`. This has worked fine up until Swift 4 and Xcode 9. Since then no matter what I do **only** the `cancel` selector is ever call, even from the `done` UIBarButtonItem  `#selector`.

I'm completely out of ideas why only one selector is ever called. Even when I've done a quick hack to make all buttons call the `done` function the `cancel` is still called.

My UIBarButtonItems are init by `McPickerBarButtonItem.swift` [class functions](https://github.com/kmcgill88/McPicker-iOS/blob/master/McPicker/Classes/McPickerBarButtonItem.swift#L36) like so:

```
self.init(barButtonSystemItem: barButtonSystemItem, target: mcPicker, action: #selector(McPicker.done))
```

Calls the below in `McPicker.swift`:

```
@objc internal func done() {
   self.doneHandler(self.pickerSelection)
   self.dismissViews()
}

@objc internal func cancel() {
   self.cancelHandler()
   self.dismissViews()
}
```

Again, if I set `#selector(McPicker.done)` or `#selector(McPicker.cancel)`, **only** `#selector(McPicker.cancel)` is ever called.
I'm out of ideas why this would be happening any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you replace `#selector(McPicker.done)` with `Selector("done")`?

Comment: @KevinBallard, tried that too. Same issue, it still calls `func cancel()`. Driving me crazy!

Comment: What happens if you log the button's `action ` property at the time it's clicked? Perhaps the nib is changing it after the fact.

Comment: @CharlesSrstka when I set a breakpoint and print out the items in the toolbar po toolbar.items,...looks right.
    `- 1 : <McPicker.McPickerBarButtonItem: 0x7fd3286152c0> target=0x7fd3286136e0 action=cancel systemItem=Cancel
    - 2 : <McPicker.McPickerBarButtonItem: 0x7fd3286156b0> systemItem=FlexibleSpace
    - 3 : <McPicker.McPickerBarButtonItem: 0x7fd328615540> target=0x7fd3286136e0 action=done systemItem=Done`

Comment: What happens if you have some other code that calls `mcPicker.perform(#selector(McPicker.done), with: nil, after: 0)`? What gets invoked?

Comment: doh! I just found my issue. Prior to swift 4 I got away with `self.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(cancel)))` but now no matter what is selected this tap gesture swallows up all taps, hence cancel is always called.

Answer (score 0):

This ended up not being related to `#selector`'s at all. It was actually caused by a `UITapGestureRecognizer`. I was using a tap gesture to dismiss my view. I had a `UIToolBar`, `Picker`, and `UIBarButtonItem`'s as subviews. The issue was the tap was hijacking all touches as `cancel`.

I got away with a this in Xcode 8, Swift 3 & iOS 10 but had to add the following to ignore taps unless it was the view in question for iOS 11.

```
extension McPicker : UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    public func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
        if let goodView = touch.view {
            return goodView == self
        }
        return false
    }
}
```